# Adding a foreign key constraint referencing to primary key columns

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, constraints, primary-key

I am applying a foreign key constraint to a table(datareal.official). Should I always refer to the same columns in the primary key of the other tabel (datareal.officialcarriage). Or could I theoretically also use difference in the reference table?

```
  ALTER TABLE datareal.official                                 
 ADD CONSTRAINT FK_carriage FOREIGN KEY 
(target,goal)
REFERENCES datareal.officialcarriage (target,goal)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: A foreign key points to a primary key or a unique key

Comment: Yes...but  can the primary key contain a different number of columns than the foreign key?

Comment: no, the point is to uniquely identify a row. So you need the entire key